# get file extension from async guzzle request

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm using guzzle to retrieve images from urls. Some of these urls are from s3. s3 uses the `application/octet-stream` content type for images. I don't think I have access to the `$request` object in the `fulfilled` callback so I can't see if the extension is in the url. Do I have any way to guess an extension in the `fulfilled` callback when the content type is `application/octet-stream`?

```
<?php

function getExtension(Response $response) {
    $contentType = explode(';', $response->getHeaderLine('Content-Type'), 2)[0];
    $extensions = [
        'image/png' => '.png',
        'image/jpg' => '.jpg',
        'image/jpeg' => '.jpeg',
        'image/gif' => '.gif',
        'image/tiff' => '.tiff',
        'image/bmp' => '.bmp',
        'application/octet-stream' => false
    ];

    return $extensions[$contentType] ?? null;
}

$client = new Client();
$pool = new Pool($client, $requests, [
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'fulfilled' => function ($response) use ($zip) {

            $ext = getExtension($response);

            if (null === $ext) {
                return;
            }

            if (false === $ext) {
                // figure out the extension somehow
                // $ext = ".foobar";
            }

            $id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
            $filename = $id . $ext;

            $zip->addFromString($filename, (string)$response->getBody());
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
            // no-op
        }
    ]
);

$pool->promise()->wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with Guzzle 6, we lost the ability to perform the following: `$response->getEffectiveUrl()`.

All you need is middleware (or a handler) that writes the request url into a response header.  Then the url becomes accessible through `$response->getHeader('myRequestUrlHeader')[0]`.